# Why same command fails in GitLab CI?

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

The following command works perfectly on the terminal but the same command fails in GitLab CI.

```
echo Hello >> foo.txt; cat foo.txt | grep "test"; [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo fail || echo success
```

return is `success`
but the same command in GitLab CI

```
$ echo Hello >> foo.txt; cat foo.txt | grep "test"; [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo fail || echo success
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

is simply failing. I have no idea why.
`echo $SHELL` return `/bin/bash` in both.

Comment: Which shell are you using in your GitLab job?

Comment: @GlenThomas `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Source of the issue

The behavior you observe is pretty standard given the "implied" `set -e` in a CI context.

To be more precise, your code consists in three compound commands:

```sh
echo Hello >> foo.txt
cat foo.txt | grep "test"
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo fail || echo success
```

And the `grep "test"` command returns a non-zero exit code (namely, `1`). As a result, the script immediately exits and the last line is not executed.

Note that this feature is typical in a CI context, because if some intermediate command fails in a complex script, we'd typically want to get a failure, and avoid running the next commands (which could potentially be "off-topic" given the error).

You can reproduce this locally as well, by writing for example:

```
bash -e -c "
echo Hello >> foo.txt
cat foo.txt | grep "test"
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo fail || echo success 
"
```

which is mostly equivalent to:

```
bash -c "
set -e
echo Hello >> foo.txt
cat foo.txt | grep "test"
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo fail || echo success 
"
```

#### Relevant manual page

For more insight:

- on `set -e`, see [`man 1 set`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/set.1posix.html)
- on `bash -e`, see [`man 1 bash`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html#options)

#### How to fix the issue?

You should just adopt another phrasing, avoiding `[[ $? -eq 0 ]]` a-posteriori tests. So the commands that may return a non-zero exit code without meaning failure should be "protected" by some `if`:

```
echo Hello >> foo.txt
if cat foo.txt | grep "test"; then
  echo fail
  false  # if ever you want to "trigger a failure manually" at some point.
else
  echo success
fi
```

Also, note that **`grep "test" foo.txt`** would be more idiomatic than `cat foo.txt | grep "test"` − which is precisely an instance of [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) (useless use of cat).

Comment: I was just reading useless use of cat before you wrote that :D thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

> I have no idea why.

Gitlab executes each command one at a time and checks the exit status of each command. When the exit status is not zero, the job is failed.

There is no `test` string inside `foo.txt`, so the command `cat foo.txt | grep "test"` exits with nonzero exit status. Thus the job is failed.