# Gitlab CI - Piped Commands in script randomly fails

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

This might be similar to [Why same command fails in GitLab CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286629/why-same-command-fails-in-gitlab-ci).

Running the identical command in GitLab CI sometimes fails.
I am extracting a string from a YAML document. It works 90% and fails 10% without any changes (selecting 'retry' in GitLab CI).
Why does this happen and how can it be fixed? My goal is to extract 'Basic-Infrastructure', the first element after 'Description:'.

Success:

```
[INFO] validate
/builds/xxx/backend/basic-infrastructure-xxxx/CloudFormation/Basic-Infrastructure-xxxx.yml
Description Line in CFN:
Description: Basic-Infrastructure | Infrastruktur fuer Kunden | 50.5.1 | Fix condition for describeDBSnapshots
[INFO] PRODUCT_NAME: 'Basic-Infrastructure'
```

Error:

```
[INFO] validate
/builds/xxx/backend/basic-infrastructure-xxxx/CloudFormation/Basic-Infrastructure-xxxx.yml
Description Line in CFN:
Description: Basic-Infrastructure | Infrastruktur fuer Kunden | 50.5.1 | Fix condition for describeDBSnapshots
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Code:

```
CFN-Description-validate:
  stage: validate
  tags:
    - Development
  script:
    - |
      echo "[INFO] $CI_JOB_STAGE"
      echo "${TEMPLATE_PATH}"
      echo "Description Line in CFN:"
      echo "$(grep -A3 'Description' ${TEMPLATE_PATH} | head -n1)"
      export PRODUCT_NAME=$(grep -A3 'Description' ${TEMPLATE_PATH} | head -n1 | cut -d '|' -f 1 | grep -Po 'Description:\K.*' | xargs)
```

Comment: I am now using `readarray -d '|' -t arr <<<"$(grep -A3 'Description' ${TEMPLATE_PATH} | head -n1)"` which seems to be a more solid solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why that export ever works, with that final `| xargs` at the end of the line, without a command.

Comment: Question: why do `grep -A3` (which produces 4 lines) if you then pipe it through `head -n1`?

Comment: Indeed the grep could be better. xargs removes leading and trailing whitespaces. Turns out gitlab ci does not deal well with multiple piped commands.

Comment: Good to know about xargs used that way, I was not aware of that usage.